# Add something to formula to remove text and add tickbox

Tags: google-sheets

=ARRAYFORMULA({{"Additional Programs - Bush"};IF(B2:B="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B,FILTER({Data!B:B&Data!C:C,Data!E:U},Data!P:P="Bushcare"),{13},0)))})

I need CHAR(9745)somewhere in this formula, if you look at the output in 'Consolidated Sheet' column L to P, it has text content but I want it to have a tickbox instead of the words: Bush, Homework Club, Garden Club, SRC etc...but I don't know where to place this in the formula, any help?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JxxmW5v3UZQ-KNtcX7P86LCpJRAke8lUBA7EP0MnHX4/edit?usp=sharing

Please help!

Comment: There is no ARRAYFORMULA in [tag:excel]; perhaps you meant [tag:google-sheets] and/or [tag:formulas].

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the formula in L1 to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"Additional Programs - Bush"};IF((len(B2:B))*(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B,FILTER({Data!B:B&Data!C:C,Data!E:U},Data!P:P="Bushcare"),{13},0))), char(9745),)})
```

If this works, you can apply the same logic to the other columns.